# Saber si dos matrices son iguales en Java

Tags: java, array, condiciones, matrices

Dos matrices 2x3 entera y determinar si sus contenidos son exactamente iguales.
He usado el if sin equals ejemplo (matriz[i][j] == matriz2[i][j]) y esta última con el Arrays.equals y ni así logro que dé, solo me dice que las matrices no son iguales y no se cual es la razón.

```
public class Ejercicio19 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    int matriz [][] = new int [2][3];
    int matriz2 [][] = new int [2][3];
    System.out.println("Ingrese valores");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero primer matriz");
            matriz[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero segunda matriz");        
            matriz2[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
                }
            }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            System.out.print(matriz2[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
            if (Arrays.equals(matriz, matriz2)){
                    System.out.println("son iguales");
                    }
            else{
                System.out.println("no son iguales ");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: matriz[i][j].equals(matriz2[i][j]) probaste esto???

Comment: usa  `if Arrays.deepEquals(matriz1, matriz2){}` Arrays.deepEquals() se utiliza para verificar si dos matrices de matrices unidimensionales o multidimensionales son iguales o no.

Comment: @Dramaturgo, si es un ejercicio de clase para aprender a manejar arrays dudo que les dejen usar los métodos de la clase Arrays, perdería todo el sentido el ejercicio :)

Comment: @Benito-B op hace uso del método propio de la clase Arrays, la idea de la respuesta ya se encontraba en el comentario anterior al mío aunque en vez de equals seria ==,... solo comente otra manera de resolverlo :)

Answer (score 0):

En realidad deberías usar [Arrays.deepEquals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) ("Si ambos argumentos son matrices, el algoritmo en `Arrays.deepEquals` se usa para determinar la igualdad") en lugar de [Arrays.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) y no necesitas realizar otro bucle para realizar la comparación.

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
int matriz [][] = new int [2][3];
int matriz2 [][] = new int [2][3];

System.out.println("Ingrese valores");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese numero primer matriz");
        matriz[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese numero segunda matriz");        
        matriz2[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
System.out.println("");
for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
    System.out.println("");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.print(matriz2[i][j]+" ");
    }
}  
System.out.println("");

 //*Realiza comparación.
 if (Arrays.deepEquals(matriz, matriz2)){
    System.out.println("son iguales");     
 }else{
    System.out.println("no son iguales");
 }
```